# I have json in below format, how can i Deserialize it in C#

Tags: c#, json, rest, json-deserialization

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "custid1": 723,
        "custid2": 670,
        "custid3": 430
    }
}
```

It doesn't have key-value pair it just contains the value of two columns. I have tried it by converting it into a data table but not getting the required result.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class like below. and then use [NewtonSoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize it to the class object.

```
public class Data
{
    public int custid1 { get; set; }
    public int custid2 { get; set; }
    public int custid3 { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Code to deserialize:

```
string json = <yourjson>;

Example ex = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(json);
```

You can see the nugget package details [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize it to `ExpandoObject`

```
ExpandoObject object1 =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json);
```